# How to decide about the convergence of $\sum(n\log n\log\log n)^{-1}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

In Baby Rudin, Theorem 3.27 on page 61 reads the following:

> Suppose $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq a_3 \geq \cdots \geq 0$. Then the seires $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the series 
>   $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k a_{2^k} = a_1 + 2a_2 + 4a_4 + 8a_8 + \ldots$$ converges.

Now using this result, Rudin gives Theorem 3.29 on page 62, which states that

> If $p>1$, $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\log n)^p} $$ converges; if $p \leq 1$, the series diverges.

Right after the proof of Theorem 3.29, Rudin states on page 63:

> This procedure may evidently be continued. For instance, $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n \log \log n}$$ diverges, whereas $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n (\log \log n)^2}$$ converges.

How do we derive these last two divergence and convergence conclusions 
by continuing the above procedure as pointed out by Rudin?

I mean how to prove the convergence of the seires 
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n (\log \log n)^2}?$$

And, how to prove the divergence of $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n \log \log n}$$ using the line of argument suggested by Rudin?

Comment: It is worth noting that the result is obvious from the integral test. For example consider $\frac{d(\ln\ln\ln(n))}{dn}$ and $\frac{d(1/(\ln\ln(n))^{p-1})}{dn}$ for $p>1$.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490309/sum-frac1n-log-n-sum-frac1n-log-n-log-log-n-etc-diverge-wh

Answer (score 7):

According to Rudin's criterion (or whatever its name is)
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n (\log \log n)^p}$$
converges iff
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{2^k \log (2^k) (\log \log (2^k))^p}
$$
converges or equivalently if
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k\log 2 (\log (k\log 2))^p}=
\frac{1}{\log 2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k (\log k+\log\log 2)^p}
$$
converges.
But
$$
\log k\ge \log k+\log\log 2\ge \frac{1}{3}\log k,
$$
and hence the sum
$$
\frac{1}{\log 2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k (\log k+\log\log 2)^p}$$
converges iff
$$
\frac{1}{\log 2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k (\log k)^p}
$$
converges, which we already know that it converges iff $p>1$.

Comment: Yiorgos S. Smyrlis, how we obtain the inequality $\log k + \log\log 2 \geq \frac{1}{2} \log k$ for $k \geq 4$?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud, $\log{k} + \log{\log{2}} \geq \frac{1}{2}{\log{k}}$ is equivalent to the inequality $\log{\log{2^k}} \geq {\log{\sqrt{k}}}$, which in turn is equivalent to $2^k \geq e^{\sqrt{k}}$, which is valid for $k \geq 4$.

Comment: Yiorgos S. Smyrlis, how to verify using the elementary means that $2^k \geq \exp^{\sqrt{k}}$? I would prefer to use only those facts that Rudin has explicitly mentioned till this point in his book.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood, it is better to come to this question after you have developed enough machinery, otherwise this exercise becomes unnecessarily difficult. I think Rudin's main motive here is just to point out that there is no 'boundary' between convergent and divergent series. Skim this question in first reading, dig deeper this question only in later readings.

Comment: $log(log(2)) < 0$ so why is $log(log(2)) + log(k) > log(k)$

Comment: @AnotherPerson It is not hard to show that $$\log k+\log \log 2>\frac{1}{3}\log k,$$ for $k\ge 2$.

Answer (score 4):

Using this method which's called *Cauchy condensation* we get

$$\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{2^k}{2^k\ln 2^k\ln\ln(2^k)}=\frac1{\ln2}\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1{k\ln(k\ln2)}\sim\frac1{\ln2}\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1{k\ln(k)}$$
so the series

$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n\ln n\ln(n\ln n)}$$
is divergent. Can you now solve the second series?

Comment: Sami Ben Romdhane, what is the meaning of the symbol $~$ that you've used in your answer?

Comment: The symbol $\sim$ means: *asymptotically equivalent*.

Comment: Sami Ben Romdhane, I'm afraid I'm not aware of the concept of "asymptotically equivalent".

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be any given positive real number. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq 3$, we have 
$$ \frac{ 1 }{ n \ln n (\ln \ln n )^p } > \frac{ 1 }{ (n+1) \ln (n+1) (\ln \ln (n+1) )^p } > 0. $$
Thus the series 
$$ \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln n (\ln \ln n)^p}$$
converges if and only if the series 
$$ \sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln n (\ln \ln n)^p}$$
converges, and the latter series converges if and only if the series 
$$ \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{2^k \ln 2^k \left( \ln \ln 2^k \right)^p} =  \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{ k (\ln 2) \  ( \ln k + \ln \ln 2 )^p } $$ converges, and the last series converges if and only if the series 
$$ \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{ k ( \ln k + \ln \ln 2 )^p } \tag{A} $$ converges.

Now we have the following result:

> Let $\sum x_n$ and $\sum y_n$ be series of positive real numbers such that the limit $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ x_n }{y_n} $$ exists in the extended real number system. Then the following three statements hold.
>
> (a) Suppose that $$ 0 <  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ x_n }{y_n} < +\infty. $$ Then $\sum x_n$ converges if and only if $\sum y_n$ converges.
>
> (b) Suppose that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ x_n }{y_n} = 0. $$ If $\sum y_n$ converges, then so does $\sum x_n$.
>
> (c) Suppose that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ x_n }{y_n} = +\infty. $$ If $\sum x_n$ converges, then so does $\sum y_n$.

Here is the  proof:

> Let us put $$ l \colon= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ x_n }{y_n}. $$
>
> (a) If $0 < r < +\infty$, then $0 < r/2 < +\infty$ as well, and thence for all sufficiently large $n$, we have 
>   $$ \left\lvert \frac{ x_n }{y_n}  - r \right\rvert < \frac{r}{2},  $$
>   which is equivalent to 
>   $$ \frac{l}{2} < \frac{x_n}{y_n} < \frac{3l}{2}, $$
>   which in turn implies 
>   $$ \frac{l}{2} y_n < x_n < \frac{3l}{2} y_n $$
>   for all sufficiently large $n$. Now we can apply Theorem 3.25 (a) in Rudin to arrive at our desired result.
>
> (b) If $l = 0$, then we have 
>   $$ 0 <  \frac{x_n}{y_n}  =  \left\lvert \frac{x_n}{y_n} - 0 \right\rvert < 1,$$
>   and hence $$ x_n < y_n, $$ 
>   for all sufficiently large $n$, and we can again apply Theorem 3.25 (a) in Baby Rudin.
>
> (c) If $l = +\infty$, then we have 
>   $$ \frac{x_n}{y_n} > 1, $$
>   and hence $$ x_n > y_n, $$
>   for all sufficiently large $n$, and again Theorem 3.25 (a) in Rudin leads to our desired conclusion.

Now let us put 
$$ x_k \colon= \frac{1}{ k ( \ln k + \ln \ln 2 )^p }, $$
and 
$$ y_k \colon= \frac{1}{ k ( \ln k )^p } $$
for each $k \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $k \geq 2$.

Then we note that 
$$ \frac{x_k}{y_k} = \frac{ \frac{1}{ k ( \ln k + \ln \ln 2 )^p }  }{ \frac{1}{ k ( \ln k )^p } } = \frac{ ( \ln k )^p  }{ ( \ln k + \ln \ln 2 )^p } = \frac{ 1 }{  \left( 1 + \frac{ \ln \ln 2 }{ \ln k } \right)^p },  $$
and thus 
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{ x_k }{y_k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{ 1 }{  \left( 1 + \frac{ \ln \ln 2 }{ \ln k } \right)^p } = \frac{ 1 }{ (1 + 0)^p} = 1. $$
So the series $\sum x_n$  converges if and only if the series $\sum y_n$ converges. Now we know from Theorem 3.29 in Baby Rudin that the series $\sum y_n$ converges for $p > 1$ and diverges for $0 < p \leq 1$. Therefore, the series in (A) above converges for $p > 1$ and diverges for $0 < p \leq 1$.

Hence our original series converges for $p > 1$ and diverges for $0 < p \leq 1$.

As for $p = 0$, we note that the series 
$$ \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \lin n} $$
diverges, again by Theorem 3.29 in Rudin.

Finally, for $p < 0$, we note that for sufficiently large $n$, 
$$ 0 < ( \ln \ln n )^p < 1, $$
and so 
$$ \frac{1 }{ ( \ln \ln n )^p } > 1, $$
which implies that 
$$  \frac{ 1 }{ n \ln n \ ( \ln \ln n )^p } > \frac{1 }{ n \ln n}. \tag{B} $$

Now as the series $$ \sum \frac{1}{n \ln n}$$ diverges by Theorem 3.29 in Rudin, so we can conclude from (B) and Theorem 3.25 (b) in Rudin that the series 
$$  \frac{ 1 }{ n \ln n \ ( \ln \ln n )^p } $$
diverges.

Hence our original series converges for $p > 1$ and diverges for $p \leq 1$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I would be grateful if you could take time reviewing my answer and comment on how good it is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson can you please go through and comment on my answer? It would be really very kind of you!!

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I've just answered my question. I would be so kind of you to have a look at it and then give your valuable thoughts on it!!